# Misalignment of links in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am trying to create a horizontal navigation with links on the right and the left.

The items on the left do not appear to have the 3px vertical padding and so are vertically aligned to the top of the DIV, whereas the items on the right are vertically aligned correctly.

This happens in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong or what I need to do to make Chrome work without changing Firefox's behaviour.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Navigation</title>
  <style>
    * { border: red solid 1px; }  
    div { border: green solid 1px; }
    body { width: 90%; margin-left: 5%; }
    body { background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #FFFFFF; }

    #navFull { background-color: #DDDDDD; color: #222222;
      margin: 1px;
      padding: 3px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    #navFull a { background-color: #222222; color: #DDDDDD;
      padding: 3px 7px; 
      text-decoration: none;
      border: white solid 1px;
    }
    #navFull a:link {}
    #navFull a:visited {}
    #navFull a:hover {background-color: #DDDDDD; color:#222222; }
    #navFull a:active {}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=pgFull>
    <div id=navFull>
      <span id=navLeft>
           <a href=#>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Albums&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
           <a href=#>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tags&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
      </span>


      <span id=navRight style="float:right;"><a href=#>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
           <a href=#>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Help&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <input type="button" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;styled text button&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                 style="background-color:#c00; color:#fff;" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Left and Right Nav has your 3px padding.

The difference is due to your input element into the right Nav that has a default margin.
 Simply add a css for your input :

```
#navFull input{
    margin:0px;
}
```

Now, if you adjust your padding:3px for higher value, Left and Right will always be impacted the same way.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tScpK/)**

Comment: Brilliant - my hero.  I spent ages trying to work out what I had done wrong.  I can't vote up as I am a new user. Many Thanks